# How does bash/scp expand out "remote" glob patterns?

Tags: linux, bash, exec, glob

If I execute (in bash):

```
scp remote.machine:/var/log/sy* .
```

I get all the files which match /var/log/sy* on the *remote* machine.

```
syslog                                     100%   91KB  10.1KB/s   00:09    
syslog.1                                   100%  753KB  62.7KB/s   00:12    
syslog.2.gz                                100%   55KB   7.9KB/s   00:07    
syslog.3.gz                                100%   50KB   8.3KB/s   00:06
```

How can this work?

I was under the impression that glob patterns were expanded by the shell *before* the command was executed.

Is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. But:

Your local shell cannot expand `remote.machine:/var/log/sy*`, because you don't have such a file (probably; a directory `remote.machine:` in the current folder with the sub directory tree `var/log/` containing `sy*` files is very rare.

So your shell gives the string to `scp` unexpanded, which hands it over to the remote system, which parses and uses it.

Answer (score 3):

If the shell doesn't find a match it keeps the asterisk.  As you don't have a file `remote.machine:/var/log/sy` there isn't anything to expand so the asterisk stays and is passed on to the remote machine.