# Function calling scp behaves unexpectedly when using * wildcard

Tags: bash, scp

I have a shell function to help me scp files to and from servers. Both servers are running bash on Ubuntu 22.04. Let's call the server `comp2` and pretend its IP address for is 192.168.1.2

On my server in the `/home/.bashrc` file I have this as my alias:

```
tocomp2() {
scp "$1" comp2@192.168.1.2:"$2"
}
fromcomp2() {
scp comp2@192.168.1.2:"$1" "$2"
}
```

Let's pretend I have three files `foo1` `foo2` and `foo3` in my working directory, and three files `bar` `bar2` `bar3` in the home directory of `comp2`. Odd things happen when I use the wildcard to move these files.

`tocomp2 foo* /home/` only transfers `foo1`

`tocomp2 foo\* /home/` doesn't find any files.

`fromcomp2 bar* ./` or `fromcomp2 bar\* ./` transfers all three `bar` files

EDIT: Better question to ask is, how can I make `tocomp2` act like `fromcomp2` where the wildcard actually selects all `foo` files?

Comment: This isn't really about programming, so it's probably off topic here. You may have better luck at https://superuser.com (another Stack Exchange site, sibling to this one)

Comment: It's only odd if you aren't expecting the shell to expand the wild card into multiple arguments, which it does.

Comment: Remote paths, though, *are* subject to expansion at the other end, which is why "comp2@192.168.1.2:bar*` will select multiple files to copy. I don't see this explicitly documented in `man scp`, though.

Comment: Edited my actual question to better phrase this as a programming question about how to improve `tocomp2`

Comment: Not a single thing in your question is actually an alias -- these are all functions. (Functions and aliases have _very_ different semantics -- positional arguments don't work right in true aliases at all).

Comment: @AlexKrohn, ...anyhow, if you want to force the local shell to expand a glob (against _local_ files), remote the quotes. (Before doing so, you probably should clear IFS locally to the function so you don't additionally get wordsplitting)

Comment: One could argue that the programming question underlying this misunderstanding is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248630/how-to-control-when-glob-is-expanded-pass-glob-into-bash-script-from-sh-and-the -- at least, that covers the aspects that chepner's comments above don't. (A subset of the -- accurate -- content from those comments is also covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678694/how-does-bash-scp-expand-out-remote-glob-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo*` expands to as many arguments as there are matching files (or the one literal argument `foo*` if no matches are found). If you have the files `foo1` `foo2` and `foo3` in your directory then it expands to three arguments so `tocomp2 foo* /home/` has four arguments in total and you are only referencing the first two in your code.

`foo\*` passes the literal argument `foo*`, and the quotes in `"$1"` disable the pathname expansion so it remains a literal argument.

A common fix is to put the known arguments in front and the variable arguments at the end of the call, then you can use `"$@"` to reference them all without knowing the exact count.

```
tocomp2() {
  dest="$1" ; shift # capture the known argument and then discard from the arg list
  scp "$@" comp2@192.168.1.2:"$dest"
}
tocomp2 /home/ foo*
```

If you don't like the reversed syntax then you can pull the last argument off the list and build a new array with everything except it:

```
tocomp2() {
  dest="${@: -1}" # destination is the last argument
  files=( "${@:1:$(( $# - 1 ))}" )
  scp "${files[@]}" comp2@192.168.1.2:"$dest"
}
tocomp2 foo* /home/
```

Comment: I prefer this solution as it keeps the same intuitive syntax of `tocomp2` files to send  + destination. Thank you!

Comment: Think about declaring your variables so they're local to the function; `local dest` at the top of the first implementation, or `local dest; local -a files` for the second, will stop those variables from leaking into global scope after the function is called.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `tocomp2 foo* /home/` expands to `tocomp2 foo1 foo2 foo3 /home/` which copies `foo1` but renames it to `foo2`, and ignores the remaining arguments.

Writing functions where the *first* argument is special is simpler; with

```
tocomp3(){
    local dest=$1
    shift
    scp "$@" "comp2@192.168.1.2:$dest"
}
```

you could get what you want with `tocomp3 . foo*` where `.` is the destination directory at the target.